# Read from line with sscanf, including whitespaces, breaking on other character

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I'm sorry for the sloppy title, but I didn't know how to format my question correctly. I'm trying to read a .txt, of which every line has information needed to fill a struct. First I use `fgets` to read the line, and then i was going to use `sscanf` to read the individual parts. Now here is where I'm stuck: normally `sscanf` breaks off parts on whitespaces, but I need the whitespace to be included. I know that `sscanf` allows ignoring whitespaces, but the tricky part is that I then need some other arbitrary character to separate the parts. For example, I have to break the line

> Carl Sagan~Contact~scifi~1997

up into parts for `Author,Name,Genre,year`. You can see I need the space in `Carl Sagan`, but I need the function to break off the strings on the tilde character. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is delimited by `~` or for instance any specific character:
Use this:

```
sscanf(s, "%[^~]", name);
```

`[^` is conversion type, that matches all characters except the ones listed, ending with `]`

Here is the sample [program](https://ideone.com/A1Z7Mc) for testing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    char *s = "Carl Sagan~Contact~scifi~1997";
    char name[100], contact[100], genre[100];
    int yr;

    sscanf(s, "%99[^~]~%99[^~]~%99[^~]~%d", name, contact, genre, &yr);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", name, contact, genre, yr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know about that ^ trick yet, thanks!

Comment: How would I go about this if the year (int) was in between the name and the genre though?

Comment: Since `~` is not a valid number, `scanf("%[^~]~%d~%[^~]", name, &nyr, genre);`, all characters explicitly specified like `~` are matched as it is by scanf.

Comment: Suggest `sscanf(s, "%99[^~]~%99[^~]~%99[^~]~%d",...` to avoid buffer overflow.  (Obviously can't happen in this example, but as a good programming practice.)

Answer (score 0):

You need `strtok`. Use `~` as your delimiter.

See the documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok

`strtok` has some drawbacks but it sounds like it will work for you.

EDIT:

After reading [this](http://unixplatform.blogspot.com/2010/01/avoiding-costly-strtok-call-sscanf-call.html), it sounds like you can use `sscanf` cleverly to achieve the same result, and it may actually be safer after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* mystrsep(char** input, const char* delim)
{
  char* result = *input;
  char* p;

  p = (result != NULL) ? strpbrk(result, delim) : NULL;

  if (p == NULL)
    *input = NULL;
  else
  {
    *p = '\0';
    *input = p + 1;
  }

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "Carl Sagan~Contact~scifi~1997";
  const char delimiters[] = "~";
  char* ptr;
  char* token;

    ptr = str;
  token = mystrsep(&ptr, delimiters);
  while(token)
    {
      printf("%s\n",token);
       token = mystrsep(&ptr, delimiters);
    }   
  return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
Carl Sagan
Contact
scifi
1997
```